# Tensorboard shows almost empty window and prints errors

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.5, tensorboard

I've compiled Tensorflow for python 3.5 on AWS instance, then upgraded it to 0.8 the same way, cleared 6006 port.

Here's what I get:

[image]

Pressing on any buttons doesn't do anything.

It outputs some errors into terminal though:
http://pastebin.com/ZxwwweFE

Here's what in those folders that it says don't have some files

```
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard$ ls
backend  dist  __init__.py  lib  __pycache__  tensorboard.py

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/lib$ ls
__init__.py  __pycache__  python
```

What do I do?

Comment: does the directory you specified with logdir has tensorflow summaries files ?

Comment: @fabrizioM here's how it looks on my home install with a random directory without files http://i.imgur.com/kx8QTas.png